# Lambda expression not working

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to clear all existing selections of a property but its not working with a lambda expression.

I have tried using "All" but it return a bool and does not work in this case. How can I accomplish this using lambda?

```
var permGroup =  (ObservableCollection<PermissionGroup>)
                       this.choicesOptionsTree.ItemsSource;

// NOT WORKING 
permGroup.All(pg => pg.Permissions.All); 

// WORKING               
//clear all existing selections).
foreach (var perGrp in permGroup)
{
    foreach (var perm in perGrp.Permissions)
    {
        perm.Selected = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `pg.Permissions.All` ?

Comment: It looks like you're merely calling a property, and not a method call.

Comment: @leppie Permissions seems to be another enumeration and All would be the LINQ-ALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`All()` is for determining if all elements in the collection satisfy a given condition, not for performing an action on all elements.

You want to use `ForEach()` -

```
permGroup.ForEach(pg => pg.Permissions.ForEach(perm => perm.Selected = false));
```

Comment: ObservableCollection doesn't have a ForEach method.. List<T> does.

Comment: You realise he's casting `permGroup` to an `ObservableCollection<T>` yes?

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but the question is, can he change it? or does he really needs to use it in that way?

Comment: ..perhaps consider casting it to a List and explaining that then? As it stands, your example will not compile.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
foreach (var perm in permGroup.SelectMany(x => x.Permissions))
{
  perm.Selected = false;
}
```

Comment: Dosent this just loop thru one permGroups Permissions?

Comment: This is the best answer by far because it doesn't make the assumption that the OP will know to cast to a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
permGroup.ForEach(pg => pg.Permissions.ForEach(p => p.Selected = false));
```

Comment: Why are you sure that `pg.Permissions` is enumerable?

Comment: @PLB If it's not enumerable you wouldn't be able to use `foreach` too :/

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I have not read complete code. My fault. I thought `All` was a property of type of `pg.Permissions`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another couple of ways

```
permGroup.SelectMany(pg => pg.Permissions).ForEach(x => x.Selected = false);
```

or

```
foreach (var permission in groups.SelectMany(x => x.Permissions))
                permission.Selected = false;
```